# Browser will not display image

Tags: html, macos, textedit

I'm building a simple website example where I added an image. I'm using textedit on mac. However, special characters are being added to the file when I look in  Chrome's inspector.

In textedit I type

```
<img src =“images/nicole.png”>
```

But it displays as

```
<img src="â€œimages/nicole.pngâ€"">
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: don't use smart quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote you are currently using is a Unicode version (Most likely the Chinese version). That's why it is showing as those weird chars. Try to copy and paste this " into your code instead of typing them in should fix it. You might want to check your IME setting or text editor setting to prevent it in the future.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I normally use Sublime Text. I'm working on someone else's mac and have no idea how things are setup.

Comment: @brewpixels Just go into the TextEdit settings and find the option to disable “smart quotes”.

Answer (score 2):

In the TextEdit preferences (TextEdit menu > Preferences), uncheck "Smart quotes" under Options.

You will have to go through and replace all of them.

Comment: I unchecked smart quotes and relaunched text edit. The image still shows special characters.