# The image won't display

Tags: image, html

I am trying to get an image to display on a basic webpage I am writing for a class. It just shows a box with my alternate text. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Practice Features</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src=“images/FLCLogo.JPG” alt=“Folsom”>
</body>
</html>
```

Both the textedit doc and the images folder are in the same folder. In fact, they are the only files in that particular folder.

I'm doing the coding on a Mac, if that makes a difference at all. I've viewed it on both Chrome and Safari. Same issue.

Comment: Use `""` instead of `“”`. There’s an option in TextEdit to disable smart quotes.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Browser will not display image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32534052/4642212).

Comment: Whatever he said, try downloading another text editor meant for developing: such as Atom.io or Sublime Text or similar! :)

Comment: Wow, smart quotes?! I would never have thought that could possibly be an issue! It's always the little things like this that trip me up. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You need to copy the file location..
Go to your image/properties/location+
Copy the location and paste it inside your quotes